# EditorTemplates, Expressions, and Nullable Types

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates

I'm creating an HtmlHelper extension with the intention of taking a DateTime (that may or may not be nullable) and passing it into an editor template that would allow editing the date and time separately.  For example:

HtmlHelper:

```
public static IHtmlString DateTimeFor_DateAndTime<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,Expression<Func<TModel, DateTime?>> expression,string htmlFieldName = null,object additionalViewData = null)
    {
        return htmlHelper.EditorFor(expression, 
                                    "DateTime_DateAndTime",
                                    htmlFieldName,
                                    additionalViewData);
    }
```

In the view:

```
@Html.DateTimeFor_DateAndTime(m => m.StartDate)
```

The problem is that when StartDate is not a nullable datetime, the expression that gets passed into the extension is `m => Convert(m.StartDate)`, which subsequently throws an error when it's passed into the underlying EditorFor call.  However, if I were to call EditorFor directly in the page, it has no problem dealing with a nullable datetime.

If I create the same extension method but one whose expression returns DateTime rather than DateTime?, everything works fine.

What is adding the Convert() call, and how do I prevent it?

Comment: Does the expression have to denote a DateTime? or DateTime explicitly?  Could you just say Expression<Func<TModel,object>>?

Comment: It still gets passed in wrapped in Convert().

Answer (score 0):

You're handling this wrong. Editor templates are extremely flexible on their own; there's no need for a helper.

I assume what you're ultimately trying to achieve is a different display for a "date" `DateTime` vs. a "datetime", or even just "time" `DateTime` object. The `DataType` attribute already gives you the necessary functionality for this. Just decorate your property(ies) with the appropriate one:

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Time)]
public DateTime Time { get; set; }
```

Then, you can have separate `DateTime.cshtml`, `Date.cshtml`, and `Time.cshtml` editor/display templates, each customized for the particular formatting/controls you need.

With the editor/display templates your model can be a nullable `DateTime` without causing errors if a regular `DateTime` is passed in:

```
@model DateTime?
```

There's really nothing you can't do with this alone, so I see no need for a helper at all. Even if you want a specialized template, e.g. `MySpecialDateTime.cshtml`, you can either decorate your property with `UIHint`:

```
[UIHint("MySpecialDateTime")]
public DateTime SpecialDateTime { get; set; }
```

Or, you can just pass whatever template you want to use to the call for `Html.EditorFor` or `Html.DisplayFor`:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SpecialDateTime, "MySpecialDateTime")
```

Comment: Yes, I see that there would be potential value in using attributes.  Though their benefit is hindered by the way we combine view models and business models. (We don't want to decorate business models with view logic and we don't want to re-create existing validation attributes on a view model).  But my question now is really more about the mechanics of the framework: **what is adding Convert() to the expression**?

Comment: I think you're missing the point of view models. The view model should hold your validation. The entity should only have database-level stuff like Required on a string to force NOT NULL.